# Smartphone: java not supported

Tags: java, android, smartphone

What means that android smartphone (let's say Samsung J3) does not support Java? I searched on google but I didn't find explanation what it means, what is the difference between smartphones which support Java and smartphones which does not support Java? Is anybody know? Thanks!

Comment: "What means that android smartphone (let's say Samsung J3) does not support Java?" -- please provide links to sites that make this claim.

Comment: It means that... It doesn't support java. So you can't write java apps for these phones.

Comment: a long long time ago, phones were not running android or iOS. There was this thing called JavaME (or J2ME), which was a java runtime on the phone that you could use to run applications. As far as I know, there is no widespread support for that old runtime on modern phones, so on ancient phone reviewing website, they may consider that modern phones don't support Java anymore (at least not that Java).

Comment: Thanks everyone for quick response.  @CommonsWare here is link [link](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_j3_(2016)-7760.php)

Comment: @DuškoOljača Most likely it refers to J2ME, which was the programming language for writing applications for old phones (for example Nokia 5300 -
 not smartphones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation for the site that you linked to](http://www.gsmarena.com/glossary.php3?term=java):

> Often stands for "Java ME" (the new name of J2ME, Java 2 Platform, Micro Edition). Java ME is a platform for applications running on mobile phones. These, mainly small, applications (e.g. games) can be downloaded from the Internet directly to the phone using its built-in web-browser.

What that site is referring to by "Java" is not Android apps, but old Java ME applets. Few, if any, Android devices support Java ME. Most Android devices support Android apps, and those apps can be written in the Java programming language.

Comment: thanks for the effort you have spent. Are you saying that I can go on playstore with that phone and use android apps?

Comment: @DuškoOljača: Assuming that the device ships with the Play Store, yes. Most, if not all, Samsung Android devices ship with the Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

> What means that android smartphone (let's say Samsung J3) does not support Java?

All android Apps are based on Java, so nowadays a phone running Android must support Java, I think this was the case also for the very first android versions.

> what is the difference between smartphones which support Java and smartphones which does not support Java?

A smartphone which is not capable of running Java requires you to write and compile Apps for it using another programming language.

E.g. If you want to build an App for iOS devices (iPhone, iPad) you cannot write them in Java, you have to use Swift, or for older versions of iOS, Objective-C, which is an Object Oriented version of C

**By looking at the link you shared, I think that the JAVA: no line refers to the ability to run java within the browser, and not the phone itself, which is android and should run android apps**

Comment: Thank you, @Daniele. Is that means that smartphones which does not support Java can't go on google play store and use android applications?

Comment: Exactly. All android Apps are developed in Java and run on top of a JVM

Comment: I wanted to buy Samsung Galaxy J3 (2016) to my wife for birthday. This phone is not to expensive and have good reviews. I just can't believe that Samsung made it last year and that cannot go with him on playstore. Thank you, @Daniele.

Comment: Ok, I don't know about that phone, but I should inform you that this is a programming/coding forum. And question and answers should be about it. for questions regarding hardware and phones you should go here: https://superuser.com/

Comment: Sorry, @Danielle, you are right. I'm going there. Thanks for help!

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer if it's been useful